# Flask SQLAlchemy filter by ONE to MANY

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My **Flask** application users enter some data into form which I receive on server:

```
t_date = request.form['t_date'] #convert to date
t_date = request.form['t_date'] #convert to date
certificate = request.form['certificate'] #name string
skill = request.form['skill'] #name string
...
```

Then I query needed data with flask-sqlalchemy from `MainModel` like this:

```
query = MainModel.query.filter(
        ((MainModel.from_date >= f_date) &
        (MainModel.from_date <= t_date)).self_group() |
        ((MainModel.to_date >= f_date) &
        (MainModel.to_date <= t_date)).self_group()).all()
```

1. `MainModel` has MANY to ONE `Company`(one company can have many)
2. ONE `Company` has MANY `Certificates` and MANY `Skills`

**Problem:** User wants to enter `Certificate`, `Skill` and Dates in the form and find all records under `MainModel`, but `Company` related to that record/model must contain `Certificate` and/or `Skill` requested.

**I tried:** to get all records from `MainModel` only by looping through the mentioned `query`:

```
#case where user entered only certificate, but not skill

for qry in query: #all records between selected dates from MainModel
    company = Company.query.filter_by(id=qry.company).first() #Company related to MainModel
    for item in company.certificates: #Certificates belonging to that company
        if item.name == certificate:  #comparing user input from form and if company has such 
        # if all true, put row from MainModel on dict to be returned
```

**Desired:** I am not sure if looping is causing any performance issues, but it is making the the complete code a bit messy. So how can I improve the initial `query` to avoid too many loops? Something like:

```
query I wrote above + all().filter_by(MainModel.company.certificates.contains(certificate) and .skills.contains(skill)
```

**Update** as per comment request:

Models sample:

```
class MainModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False)


class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    certificates = db.relationship('Certificate',
                                        secondary=certif_company,
                                        backref=db.backref('company',
                                                           lazy='dynamic'))


class Certificate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    certif_company = db.Table('certif_company',
        db.Column('certificate_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('certificate.id'), primary_key=True),
        db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), primary_key=True)
    )
```

Comment: Could you add the details of the various models that you are trying to query?

Comment: @JRajan yes, added a sample